# What do I do with the "Large Emerald"?

Tags: across-the-obelisk

I was doing a run and found this item, a Large Emerald:
[image: Large Emerald]

Does anyone know what to do with it? I can't find anything about this online.
What do I do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! managed to make it to the 4th act, and it seems that you take it to a shop:
[image: Emerald Shop]

Making it there, I got the following option:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also take it to The sacred forge node on the top path to unlock the Emerald Staff weapon.

[image: The sacred forge node in Act 4]